# Angular 2 - Array of Objects is still undefined after a HTTP Request

Tags: arrays, angular, object, request, undefined

I'm using [this guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) to learn angular 2 http requests. My array of objects is still undefined after an `http.get()` request.

Service code:

```
getUserCompaniesByUserId(userId: string) : Observable<ApplicationUserCompany[]> {
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/${userId}`)
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
        const body = error.json() || '';
        const err = body.error || JSON.stringify(body);
        errMsg = `${error.status} - ${error.statusText || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
        errMsg = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    }

    console.error(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

Component code:

```
getCompanies() {
    this.companyService.getUserCompaniesByUserId(localStorage.getItem('user_id'))
                            .subscribe(
                                uc => this.userCompanies = uc,
                                error => this.errorMsg = <any>error
                        );

    this.userCompanies.forEach(uc => {
        ...
        ...
    });
}
```

Because the userCompanies array is undefined after the request, it won't enter in the forEach() loop. It throws this error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined".

Not the request is the error, because I tested it with Postman and Application Insights (my API is .NET Core API). The response code is 200.
Somewhere else is the problem, but I cannot find it.

Thank you!

Comment: Try moving the foreach inside the subscribe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue is caused by the below code being fired before the http request is finished. Since the http request is ajax it get fired and then the code after that is fired.

You need to drop the below code into the callback of the subscription so that it only fires once you are sure response has been returned from the server.

```
this.companyService.getUserCompaniesByUserId(localStorage.getItem('user_id')).subscribe(
    uc => {
      this.userCompanies = uc;
      this.userCompanies.forEach(uc => { ... }); 
   },
   error => this.errorMsg = <any>error
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
this.companyService.getUserCompaniesByUserId(localStorage.getItem('user_id'))
                        .subscribe(uc => {
                         this.userCompanies = uc
                         this.userCompanies.forEach(uc => {});     
})
```